# How to find the exponent in an equation?

Tags: linear-algebra

I am not a mathematician. But I need to work out out to work with equations where the unknown is an exponent. For example, given this expression:

2<sup>x</sup> = 5/3.

How can i rewrite this equation x = ?

Thank you

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Use logarithms.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Are you familiar with logs?

Comment: Thank you. I am reading about logarithims.

Answer (score 1):

The natural way to do it would be to apply the (base $2$) logarithm to both sides of the equation.

In your case:
$$
\log_2(2^x) = \log_2\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)
$$
Then, by the properties of the logarithm you have:
$$
\log_2(2^x) = x\log_2(2) = x
$$
Thus, $x = \log_2\left(\frac{5}{3}\right)$ is the solution to your problem.